# Web Application retrieving datas from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, iis, web-applications

I have the follow (and bizzare) situation:
My web application loads some datas (by executing 1 proc) in 8 seconds
My proc, when executed directly on SQL, load in 1 seconds.

Im pretty sure there is no looping in both.

My question is:
Could bad IIS configuration cause this?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna put some word about how ur connecting to your database from your web aplication... Ofc. you get slower results from your web aplication due to your need to connect to DM, read context, transfer it, and cloase conn where on other hand in sql server ur allready connected and data is just there.

But in your case, it is kind of strange to have 800% diference from your aplication and direct sql.

btw, does your application runs on your pc same as sql server or is it on some remote server?